# More efficient way to fill out my form in protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

I have an e2e test that fills out data in a form for my application. I would like to make the code more efficient and was wondering if it is worth it or not. Basically, my code at the moment sends keys to all the required fields, then clicks a save button. From there I check if the data is displayed correctly and that a success message displays. The tests after the form being saved are not what I need to make more efficient. It is the process of filling out the form. So I was curious if anybody could provide any insight on a more practical way in doing so. I am a little confused, as protractor uses promises, so doing a loop for my form would not really work as the elements would not be visible. Also, I have an email validation and drop down menus, so doing a loop would not really work well, as there are fields that require specific format. I was thinking about creating a function that fills out the entire form, then just calling the function in my tests so that my test is more efficient. I am just unsure if it is worth it to do so. Any advice would be great. Should I just leave the code the way it is? Here is an example of the code where I fill out the form. Thank you!

```
  page.getNameInput().sendKeys('test');
  browser.sleep(1000);
  page.getLastNameField().sendKeys('testLast');
  browser.sleep(1000);
  page.getEmailField().sendKeys('test@test')

  //these are drop down menus
  page.getProgramField().sendKeys(Key.RETURN);
  page.getProgramField().sendKeys(Key.RETURN);
//2nd drop down
  page.getFileField().sendKeys(Key.RETURN);
  page.getFileField().sendKeys(Key.RETURN);
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in general it's very bad to use `browser.sleep()` since you actually cannot know the exact time an operation finishes. That's why they invented promises.

In your particular case one option would be to create a function called `async fillInput(element, text)`. This function is responsible for filling data into an `ElementFinder` object which is created using `element(by.css('SOME_CSS_RULE'))`.

```
export async function fillInput(el, text) {
  await el.click()
  await el.clear();
  await el.sendKeys(text);
}
```

In the function you can see the usage of `await`. It actually waits for resolving of a promise and unwraps it's value. That removes the pain of endless nested `promises`.`await` is available WITHIN EVERY async function. A function is asynchronus as you put the word `async` before it . 
In this case `fillInput()` returns a `Promise<void>` object because every `async` function returns a `Promise`.

With given function in combination with `await` you could do something like the following in your test:

```
// ...
var page;

t.beforeAll(function() {
  page = getMyPage();
});

t.it('should be able to fill out form' , async function() {
  await fillInput(page.getNameInput(),  'foo');
  await fillInput(page.getLastNameField(), 'bar');
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So basically await pretty much waits for the promise to be available? Would you mind explaining the line "var nameEl - page.getNameInput()"? Wouldn't I just need to use nameEl rather then getNameInput in the following line? Thanks!

Comment: Yes `await` just waits for the value of a promise. I adjusted the answer, yes you just can use `nameEl` or `page.getNameInput()` directly. It's obviously the same. Cheers!